# URL helper for a post route in a resource

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a resourceful route, with a `post` route nested within it:

```
resources :groups, :only => [:index, :show] do
  post 'send_audit_reminder', :on => :member
end
```

If I run `rake routes`, this route shows up just fine:

```
send_audit_reminder_group POST   /groups/:id/send_audit_reminder(.:format)
          {:controller=>"groups", :action=>"send_audit_reminder"}
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to refer to the `send_audit_reminder` URL for a given route. I've tried `send_audit_reminder_group_path(@group)` and `send_audit_reminder_url(@group)`, which both give me the following error:

```
No route matches {:controller=>"groups", :action=>"send_audit_reminder"}
```

As you can see from `rake routes`, there is indeed a route that matches those parameters, and there is also a matching method on the controller.

How can I find the path or URL for this route? I would like not to hard code it, since our apps are deployed to subdirectories on the same virtual host, so a hard-coded absolute path won't work.

And where would I look for documentation or information on this in the future? Since these path and URL helper methods are generated from my routes, I obviously can't look for documentation, and while `rake routes` tells me that the route is there, it doesn't appear to be there when I try and get the URL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It might be that you're missing the placeholders and it can't route because of that. The following should work based on your definition:

```
send_audit_reminder_group_path(group)
```

Any time you see identifiers like `:id` or `:group_id` in your route, you must supply them unless they are in brackets, which declares them as optional, as is the case here with `:format`. The arguments need to be supplied in the same order they are declared. For this:

```
/example/:user_id/groups/:id
```

The arguments to this route would be `user_id` and `id` and both must be supplied. Generally with routes you can either use a literal number or string, or a model that supports `to_param` as all ActiveRecord::Base-derived ones do.

This all stems from declaring with `:member`, meaning it is specific to a particular record, and not `:collection` where that is omitted. The [Rails Routing Guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) explains more.

Comment: Nope, I'm passing the group in. I'll update my question to clarify that.

Comment: Pretty tricky, especially if `@group` is defined. There's nothing in your `routes.rb` that might prevent that part from running? No conditionals? Sometimes it's worth writing functional tests to `assert_routing` and verify that your custom routes work.

Comment: My `routes.rb` is bog simple; a `root :to => redirect("/groups")`, a few resourceful routes, and the one shown, which is just stripped of a few nested resources that I figured were likely irrelevant as they have no chance of a name conflict. Nothing conditional. I'll try writing the functional tests; my test infrastructure appears to be broken at the moment, so I need to go fix that before I can get that done.

Comment: Ah. Turns out that I needed to be passing `group` not `@group`, since at this point I was in the `group` partial, not a view in which `@group` was defined. It was just a bad error message, which should have complained about a nil argument, but instead complained about a missing route that actually was there. Writing the functional test and finding that it worked led me to the answer, after I tried replacing `send_audit_reminder_url` with `url_for`, which actually reports the error about passing in `nil` properly.